# Angularfire unable to redirect after signInWithPopup()

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Using Angular2 and angularfire2 i am trying to redirect a user after they have signed into google using the "signInWithPopup" function, once the user is signed in the page immediately refreshes and loads up the front page, however i want to have it redirect the user to a different page once logged in.

The code bellow is the functionality to sign the user into google.

```
 loginWithGoogle() {
return this.authentication.auth
  .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());}
```

The code bellow is the function which attempts to log the user in, calling the function above.

```
loginWithGoogle() {
this.authentication.loginWithGoogle().then(function (result) {
  this.router.navigate(['/exampleRoute']);
}).catch(function (error) {
  alert('error');
});}
```

When the user logs in through the popup according to the firebase documentation anything inside the function should occur once sign in is complete but instead it just redirects to the '/' route. it is worth noting that once the user signs in with popup i think the page refreshes meaning that it just reloads to the first route. instead of the one i am trying to tell it to go to.

Answer (score 2):

You've lost the context of [`this`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript), use an arrow function:

```
this.authentication.loginWithGoogle().then((result) => { 
  if(result.uid !== null) {
    this.router.navigate(['/exampleRoute'])
  }
})
```

Comment: Changing it to an arrow expression doesn't seem to change the way it works at all, if i try to call an alert the alert doesn't call but if i log data to the console it is logging but still redirects to the '/' page.

Comment: How are you importing firebase auth (`firebase.auth`)?

Comment: "import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';"

that's how i'm importing the Firebase functionality.